# Mutually dependent input sliders in R shiny

Tags: r, input, shiny

I try to make two mutually dependent input sliders in a shiny app but don't seem to get it to work. I plan to use this kind of situation in a shiny app and for ease illustrate it here with a simplified 'glass half empty / full' example in which one slider should show glass fullness and one emptyness:

```
library(shiny)

ui =(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Glass fullness"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("Full", "% water", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.2),
    #display dynamic UI
    uiOutput("Empty")),
  mainPanel()
))

server = function(input, output, session){

  # make dynamic slider 
  output$Empty <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("Empty", "% air", min=0, max=1, value=1-input$Full)
  })

}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

I understand the `value = 0.2` and `value=1-input$Full` cause above code only to make the second slider dependent on the first but not the other way around. My problem is that I want to make both dependent on each other. I tried adding an uiOutput("Full") & dynamic slider for Full but did not manage to work around circular coding.

The result of above code looks as follows:

[Glass half empty/full screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSYlk.png)

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi define your sliders in the UI and updated them in the server when it's needed :

```
library(shiny)

ui =pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Glass fullness"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput(inputId = "Full", label = "% water", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.2),
    sliderInput(inputId = "Empty", label = "% air", min = 0, max = 1, value = 1 - 0.2),
    uiOutput("Empty")),
  mainPanel()
)

server = function(input, output, session){

  # when water change, update air
  observeEvent(input$Full,  {
    updateSliderInput(session = session, inputId = "Empty", value = 1 - input$Full)
  })

  # when air change, update water
  observeEvent(input$Empty,  {
    updateSliderInput(session = session, inputId = "Full", value = 1 - input$Empty)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because in the second slider you have:

```
sliderInput("Empty", "% air", min=0, max=1, value=1-input$Full)
```

where value is `1-input$Full` therefore it does depend on the first one, but in the first slider value is 0.2:

```
sliderInput("Full", "% water", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.2),
```

and due to this 0.2, there is no relation with the second one.

Although, as you mention, you will end up with circular dependency.

Comment: Thanks Leo, I edited the question to make it more clear that I understand these parts of the code lead to only one slider being dependent on the other. I try to find out how to make them mutually dependent.